# Why isn't my environmental variables working when setup in my database.yml config file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, environment-variables, tiny-tds

I have my Rails server setup currently on an Ubuntu box.  I've tried to correctly set up my username/password for my database connection by adding them as environment variables and then reference them in my `database.yml` file in my project.  When I hard code the values in my `database.yml` it works fine (as shown below).

**database.yml (hard coded)**

```
production:
  <<: *default
  adapter: sqlserver
  host: hostname-for-server
  port: 1433
  database: production
  username: domian\my_username
  password: my_password
  pool: 25
  timeout: 15000
```

Below is what I'm attempting to do but, it isn't working -- as in I get an error saying a connection can not be made with the server. Additional note on the environment variables. When I run `printenv` in Ubuntu's terminal the expected values are returned for `SQLSERVER_USER` and `SQLSERVER_PASS`.

**~/.profile**

```
#...
export SQLSERVER_USER="domain\my_username"
export SQLSERVER_PASS="my_password"
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"
```

**project\shared\config\database.yml**

```
default: &default
  pool: 25
  timeout: 15000

production:
  <<: *default
  adapter: sqlserver
  database: production
  username: <%= ENV['SQLSERVER_USER'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['SQLSERVER_PASS'] %>
  host: hostname-for-server
  port: 1433
```

Comment: When you type `env` do you see your values?

Comment: @AntarrByrd, yes as well as many other variables -- but yes my two are in the list.

Comment: Did you start your server in production mode?

Comment: @alebian, yes it's in production mode -- I also restarted after each change to my files if that helps for anything?

Comment: To be sure, that the environment variables are available in this file try replace `ENV['SQLSERVER_USER']` with `p ENV['SQLSERVER_USER']`, and similarly with the password and then start the rails console. It will throw an error, but you will be sure if the values displayed are the expected ones.

Comment: @Mareq, I just get the following: `tiny_tds/client.rb:74:in `connect': Login failed for user 'p ENV['SQLSERVER_USER']'. (TinyTds::Error)`